# How to add transition to content with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have created website for a competition and want that whenever user hovers over this link then the text changes, i have achieved the text change but now want to add a transition to it, please help me.

BY THE WAY i have used only css to change the code,

```
#link:before 
{
position:fixed;  
left:52%; 
content:"I am feeling lucky"; 
transition:content 1s;
}

#link:hover:before 
{
position:fixed; 
text-decoration:none; 
left:52%; 
color:#666; 
content:"Wrong Decision";
}
```

The transition:content 1s; has no effect please help me with the code.

Comment: Are you trying to do a CSS3 transition, or a JavaScript animation?

Comment: What kind of transition?

Comment: What kind of effect are you after? Some kind of fade-over?

Comment: i want that the change between the text is slow. sort of like a fading effect

Answer (score 2):

You can't change `content` with effect but you can use `:after` with `:before` for this and show/hide it on hover.

```
#link:before,
#link:after{
    position:fixed;
    text-decoration: none;
    left:52%; 
    content:"I am feeling lucky"; 
    transition:content 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
#link:after{
    content:"Wrong Decision";
    opacity: 0;
    color:#666;
}
#link:hover:before{opacity: 0;}
#link:hover:after{opacity: 1;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UNmab/)

Comment: Why is this two #link:after{} written?

Comment: for not to write repeated properties twice

Comment: Thanks your code helped a bit but there is still a problem. When i remove my mouse from the link, it doesn't fade, it just comes on. Though it work on the demo link you gave me.